# Error when running koudoku:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have `gem 'koudoku'` installed in my application. After running `bundle install`, I ran `rails g koudoku:install user` to install koudoku.

After running the command in my terminal, I get this error: `Could not find generator 'koudoku:install'.`

I have even re-installed the gem several times, but keep getting the same error.

Any help is much appreciate.

Comment: please post full error log

Comment: Sorry, maybe better to say Warning. But Could not find generator 'koudoku:install'. is the only warning I get

Comment: do `bundle show kouduku` and then post

Comment: MacBook-Air:app Navid$ bundle show koudoku
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/koudoku-1.2.4

Comment: please try `bundle exec rails g koudoku:install user`

Comment: Same warning/error: Could not find generator 'koudoku:install'. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `Could not find generator 'koudoku:install'` if you don't have `Stripe gem` Installed.

Remove `gem 'koudoku'`, run `bundle install` and add `Stripe gem` to your gem file and run `bundle install` to install **Stripe**.

After installing **Stripe**, you can correctly install `gem 'koudoku'` and run `rails g koudoku:install user`